# Issue calling Google API in Liferay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, liferay

I have problem with the execution of the javascript inside a jsp page. 
I have the following page which works perfectly if I call it from my filesystem, that is, I write in the address bar C:\...\heatmap2.jsp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Energy Heatmap </title>
    <style>
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 80% }
      h1 { position:absolute; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true?key=AIzaSyCzoFE1ddY9Ofv0jjOvA3yYdgzV4JvCNl4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript'>

        /*Array in cui saranno inseriti i punti da visualizzare nella mappa
        */
        var heatMapData = new Array();

        function loadHeatMapData(callback)
        {

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/EnergyManagement-portlet/api/secure/jsonws/sample/get-samples-time-by-name?energyName=EnAssGS",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(jsonData)
                {

                            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
                            {
                                var decodedData = JSON.parse(jsonData[i]);
                                var lng = decodedData["_longitude"]; 
                                var lat = decodedData["_latitude"];
                                var energyIntensity = decodedData["_value"];

                                heatMapData.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), weight: energyIntensity});
                            }
                         return callback(heatMapData);  
                         }
            })
        }

       function drawHeatMap()
       {
        // map center
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.8333333, 14.25);
        // map options,
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        // standard map
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

       var heatMap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
           data: heatMapData,
           dissipating: false
       });

       heatMap.setMap(map);

       /*
       Questi punti dovrebbero prevenire da un file.
       */    
       var vehiclePath = [
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85235, 14.26813),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85236, 14.26822),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85236, 14.26822),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85236, 14.26816),                                    
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85258, 14.26811),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85364, 14.26793),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85414, 14.26778),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.8554, 14.2676),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.8579, 14.27286),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85821, 14.27291),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.8584, 14.27302),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85859, 14.27325),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.8587, 14.27421),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85865, 14.27433),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.85866, 14.27446),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.86656, 14.291),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.86653, 14.29102)

                                    ];

       var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: vehiclePath,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
          });

          path.setMap(map);
         }   
       /*Callback*/
       loadHeatMapData(drawHeatMap)  

</script>





  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

   <p id="demo"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to call it inside my Liferay portal, I can't see any javascript running. 
The following code creates a heatmap (with the Google API), the points are obtained with an asynchronous call to the webserver 
via SOAP (it's a method available from an entity of my project).

I also tried to add the tag

```
<header-portlet-javascript>
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization sensor=true?key=AIzaSyCzoFE1ddY9Ofv0jjOvA3yYdgzV4JvCNl4"
</header-portlet-javascript>
```

with no sucess. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a point of reference, you could browse the [source code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/google-maps-portlet) for the Liferay developed Google Map portlet.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test your code currently, I see two issues with it:

Your JSP contains `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements etc. These are not allowed in portlets and won't work the same way as in a standalone page

Further, your  contains superfluous quotes.

```
<header-portlet-javascript>
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/and/so/on"
</header-portlet-javascript>
```

I'd expect this to literally be added to the page, resulting in double quotes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""https://maps.googleapis.com/and/so/on""></script>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Please check what ends up on the generated page when you add your portlet to it. Also, remove the extra quotes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Deae Olaf, 
I applied your advice to my code. 
With the support of the internet explorer debbuger, I found out that the code inside the drawHeatmpaData is like being commented (please, look at the picture)

[image].

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent from you code being commented,  I found that we cannot use // to comment,
because all the text even the code is treated as comment. 
I replace all  // with /**/ but it still does not work.